# Adjoint of a multiplication operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $B$ be the Banach space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity and defined on a locally compact Hausdorff space $X$. Given a continuous and bounded function $g$ on $X$, let $T$ be the multiplication operator by $g$: $Tf=gf$ for every $f$ in $B$.
I am almost sure that, as a consequence of the Riesz-Markov Theorem, the adjoint operator of $T$ is again a multiplication operator on the space of Borel regular complex measures on $X$. Is it true?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. Just write down the definiton of $T^*$. We have for $f \in C_0(X)$, $\mu \in M(X) = C_0(X)^*$ that 
\begin{align*} \def\sp#1{\left\langle#1\right\rangle}
  \sp{T^*\mu, f} &= \sp{\mu, Tf}\\
     &= \int_X (Tf)(x)\, \mu(dx)\\
     &= \int_X f(x)\, g(x)\, \mu(dx)\\
     &= \int_X f(x)\, (g\cdot \mu)(dx)\\
     &= \sp{g \cdot \mu, f}
\end{align*}
So $T^* \mu = g \cdot \mu$, for all $\mu$.